# Custom Derives Methods using Custom Entities in Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I want to access the list from the Custom Repository using Custom Derived methdods.
I have shared the code with explaination below:

**UserWalletHistory.java - Entity**

```
package com.ayvids.api.model.user;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "users_wallet_history")
public class UserWalletHistory {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int (11)", name = "rowid")
private int rowid;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "int (11)", name = "userid")
private User userId;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "varchar (255)", name = "remarks")
private String remarks;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "float(10,2) default '0.00' ", name = "credit")
private float credit;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "float(10,2) default '0.00' ", name = "debit")
private float debit;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "float(10,2) default '0.00' ", name = "balance")
private float balance;

@Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "datetime default current_timestamp", name = "datetime")
private LocalDateTime datetime;
}
```

**UserWalletHistoryRepo.java - Custom Repository**

```
public interface UserWalletHistoryRepo extends CrudRepository<UserWalletHistory, Integer> {

public List<UserWalletHistory> findByUserId(int userId);

}
```

**UserWalletHistoryService.java - Service Layer**

```
public List<UserWalletHistory> getByUserId(int userId) {
    return repo.findByUserId(userId);
}
```

**UserWalletHistoryController.java - Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/get/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getByUserId(@PathVariable int id) {
    List<UserWalletHistory> list = service.getByUserId(id);
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.OK, list);
    } else {
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

**The Error I receive when hitting the URL**

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1] did not match expected type [com.ayvids.api.model.user.User (n/a)]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its on many to one relation on UserWalletHistory entity on the field private User userId; as exception says, please check referencedColumnName as well .

Comment: @Lunatic How would I check the referenced ColumnName is correct or not? Please guide me for the same. Thanks in advance!